# How do I print and enter data with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to enter data into the database via the form, when the storage process is complete, the results appear on the new screen? how is the process?

thanks.

Comment: i understand you are a new member - so pls follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and read it carefully. I vote for close because its simply too broad (btw: first search on google resulted in https://selftaughtcoders.com/creating-processing-form-codeigniter/ maybe it helps but Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a really simple tutorial on how to achieve that in the codeigniter docs.

[Codeigniter Tutotial - Getting started](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html)